# JQuery not summing the values of a set of input boxes in certain situations

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, class, onchange

I am using the following function by calling it inside `document.Ready()` that is defined inside a file called `startSript.js` file to sum the values of a set of input boxes.

The one example of a call to this function would be: `autoSumBySelector('.class1', 'outputClass1')` that would sum the values of input boxes with class attribute `class1` and display the sum in a div tag with class attribute `outputClass1`.

The function works fine except that after inputting the values into input boxes (of say `class1`) if I change the value of one of those input boxes to 0 or if I remove that value completely to make it blank. In that case, the output div tag would not change the value.

Say, if I input the values 5,10,15 in three boxes, the output div would correctly display 30. And if I change the value 10 to 1 the sum would correctly display as 21. But if I change any of the three values to 0 or blank, the output div would not change and would still display the previous value (say, 21).

```
var autoSumBySelector = function (selector, outputselector, func, fixed) {

    //Attaches the Event to the selector or array of selector
    if (selector != undefined) {

        $(selector).change(function (event) {
            var validation = true;

            if (fixed == undefined) {
                fixed = 0;
            }

            if (typeof (func) == "function") {
                validation = func(this, outputselector);
            }

            if (validation) {

                //This is to sum currency value of given selector 
                var total = 0;
                $(selector).each(
                function () {
                    var vl = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
                    if (!isNaN(vl) && vl.length != 0) {
                        total += parseFloat(vl);
                    }
                });

                if (outputselector != undefined) {

                    $(outputselector).val(total).change();
                }
                else //if the output div is not defined then it returns the value
                    return sum;
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

This is an ASP.NET MVC app. I have two script files common.js and startScript.js that get loaded as follows in the Index.cshtml (a view) file) as shown below. The :

`@{
        ViewBag.Title = "App title";
    }
    @section Scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/common.js"> 
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/startScript.js">
    .........
}
<form>
HTML tags here
 .....
 partial views rendered here
</form>`

The function is defined in the common.js and the calls are made from the starScript.js as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    .....
    .....other calls
    autoSumBySelector('.class4', '.outputClass4');
    autoSumBySelector('.class3', '.outputClass3');
    autoSumBySelector('.class2', '.outputClass2');
    autoSumBySelector('.class1', '.outputClass1');
    .....other calls
}
```

Comment: A working example on http://jsfiddle.net would be helpful. Also, I hope you didn't capitalize the R in `$(document).ready({...})` in your code.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7ZmCq/) and it works perfectly for me. How are you invoking *autoSumBySelector*?

Comment: @Oscar and @Blazemonger To answer your question, I have added more details in the `Edit` section of my original post. As Oscar shows in his demo the function should work. But for some reason it's not working under two scenarios in my app.

Comment: In which browser are you testing this? Maybe it could be a specific browser question.

Comment: @Oscar, I am using IE9, 10 and Chrome 33. It's not working on both.